# PHP filter_input returns false

Tags: php, function, oop, strlen

i am using this for username-validation:

```
public function check_length($username) {   
        $username = strlen($username);
        $value = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $username, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range" => 2, "max_range" => 30)));
        if ($value) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

When i type : "anyName" the function returns FALSE, why?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` - This is validation for an INT type, not string. I think you're looking for `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

Comment: Nope. He passes the result of `strlen()`.

Comment: exactly..so where is the mistake?

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `filter_input` should be the *name* of the key to get from `$_GET` (`INPUT_GET`), *not* the value you are filtering.  What are you sending via `GET`?  How are you sending `anyName`?

Comment: Why not just check if the length is within the range using an if(...) ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `filter_input` before, I researched it, and it seems useful for emails. But, for a string, why not do something like this?

```
public function check_length($username) {   
    $username = strlen($username);
    if ($username < 2 || $username >30) {
        return false; // If username isn't valid
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

if(check_length($username)){
    // We're good to go! :-)
}else{
    // Validation criteria not met :-(
}
```